# Using custom crypto algorithms in Corda

Tags: corda

Is there a way to plug in a custom crypto algorithms to CordApps? For example, apps which are being used for russian government should meet some specific restriction policies. Please share some information regarding an enrtypoint for customization if exists.

Comment: Your question doesn't point a specific problem. Please read "how to ask" section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding transaction signing, at the moment, Corda supports 5 signature algorithms, Pure EdDSA, ECDSA using the K1 curve, ECDSA using the NIST P-256 curve, RSA and the post-quantum secure Sphincs-256 algorithms, see [here](https://discourse.corda.net/t/post-quantum-signatures-in-corda/819/4) for more.

Although the platform seems to cryptographically be one of the most agile in the DLT/Blockchain space, it is not pluggable; you cannot just add a new cryptographic provider and automatically support new cryptographic functionality.

Note that the set of signature algorithms supported forms a part of the consensus rules for a DLT network. Thus, it is important that implementations not support unconditional pluggability and do take measures to prevent algorithms supported by any underlying cryptography library from becoming accidentally accessible.

Why? Signing a transaction with an algorithm that is not a part of the base specification would result in a transaction being considered invalid by some peer nodes and thus a loss of consensus occurring. The introduction of new algorithms over time will require a global upgrade of all nodes.

On the other hand, it would perfectly make sense to support custom algorithms in special DLT networks, for instance when algorithmic restrictions/laws apply, as the OP mentions. I assume that these new algorithms should be first supported/implemented in Corda, then each network enables the desired schemes only.